# Progress Bar in WPF application for long running WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, backgroundworker

I have a long running WCF service and a client that consumes it via WPF. Am using a Progress Bar to notify the client of the percentage completion for a particular process (a method in WCF: I need to be able to display the percentage based on the looping counter in the service)

- I have used Background Worker to display progress percentage but it does not display the progress correctly. (displays just 0 and 100 not the in between values) Everything works fine in DEBUG mode but not in RELEASE mode! (Progress bar is updated sequentially in DEBUG mode)
- I tried using callbacks/wsDualHttpBinding but have some difficulty in getting this incorporated for all clients. So, had to drop this option.
- working on async/await

I have googled quite a few links but nothing helps with my problem.

Please guide me on how to get the current/running value from a method that is not complete yet from a WCF service so I could populate the progress bar percentage based on this value. (in between values)

P.S: WCF service uses wsHttpBinding

sample code below:

```
public Progress()
{
    // Start the BackgroundWorker.
         myBGWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
         myBGWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
         myBGWorker.DoWork += myBGWorker_DoWork;
         myBGWorker.ProgressChanged += myBGWorker_ProgressChanged; 
 }

public void ShowProgress()
{
    myBGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void  myBGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

       // fetches a static value from the service 
      string value = _client.Progress();

    int p=0;
       for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                // Report progress.
                p = Convert.ToInt32(_client.Progress());
                _logger.Debug("Progress5:" + p.ToString());
                 myBGWorker.ReportProgress(p, i);
            }
}

private void  myBGWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
            {
                progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand how it could be implemented. This is part of my working code.
.xaml file:

```
 <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBarCompare" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="10,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321"/>
```

Function with process:

```
       private async void btnCompare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBarCompare.Value = 0;
        lblCompare.Content = "";
        List<string> list1= (List<string>)Application.Current.Properties["list1"];
        List<string> list2= (List<string>)Application.Current.Properties["list2"];

        List<Result> output = new List<Result>();
        List<Result> passed = new List<Result>();

        int topCount = emailList.Count;
        int currentItem = 0;
        int topBound = topCount - 1;

        while (currentItem < topCount)
        {
            var hash = await CheckOperation(list1[currentItem]); // this line perform progress bar to be filled

            var result = list2.Contains(hash);

            //some operations

            if (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(100d * currentItem / topBound)) < 51)
            {
                Style style = this.FindResource("LabelTemplateNotFilled") as Style;
                lblCompare.Style = style;
            }
            else
            {
                Style style = this.FindResource("LabelTemplateFilled") as Style;
                lblCompare.Style = style;
            }

            ProgressBarCompare.Value = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(100d * currentItem / topBound));
            lblCompare.Content = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(100d * currentItem / topBound)) + "%";

            currentItem++;
        }

        lblCompare.Content = "COMPLETE";

    }
```

and core function to that:

```
private async Task<string> CheckOperation(string input)
    {
        var result = "";
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //perform some code
        });

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you SouXin. My problem here is in fetching the value from the service to the UI. It does not bind the progress data in UI. I would like to understand the ways in which I can send progress data to the client without using callbacks/duplex bindings. With wsHttpBinding, how do I fetch the in between values of a function service call from a client proxy? Am using background worker as of now, but it does not return values in release mode although it works fine in DEBUG mode. Am not quite sure on how this is happening.